# discord how to make him send a message every 15 minutes and a command to get an item and the first one to type the command get the item

Tags: discord, discord.js

(SELECT t.* FROM `test_table` t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT t.* FROM `test_table` t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`setInterval()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) function to send a message every 15 minutes.

Then you can use the [Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) page on the official discord.js guide to post any question and collect the answer.

Then you can add a function to give an item to the user who gave the correct answer.

> I hope my answer helps you.